# Google action console disabled

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've started playing around with Google's Dialogflow and created a simple project. When I go to the Google actions console the Chrome window is grayed out.

Is there perhaps something I have missed or need to enable?

Here are the steps I have taken.

1. Created a new Test project in Dialogflow
2. Created two entities under the Entities tab, namely Device and Power and called it Entities ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjYXJ.png))
3. Under Intents tab

   - Created some training phrase's
   - Entered the text "Send" in the action textbox
   - Created parameters for the two entities, @Device and @Power
     ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0UXj.png))
4. Under settings of the project

   - Deployed the project to a DEV environment ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P44r9.png))
   - Clicked on the "Manage in assistance console" on the Environments tab. I'm then redirected to the actions console page that is unfortunately disabled. ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Wr4.png))

Hoping someone will be able to assist.

Comment: Please add details like how you set this up. Also, put the complete screenshot of the console page.

Comment: I've added additional information to help explain the steps I've taken.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I contacted Google support and they were quick to respond and provide me with a resolution.

Turned out that I had a Chrome extension that affected the AoG/Dialog console behaviour. So I disabled the Chrome extension and it worked.

What you can also try for those that encounter a similar issue is to go to the console actions page in incognito window and see if that works for you.